# ParseUser setPassword() isn't saving the password

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want a unique user but I don't need it to be a formal thing for my app.  So, on launch I inspect shared preferences for a previously stored username.  I handle the user creation or login like so:

```
        String parseUsername = _appPrefs.getParseUsername();
        _progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (parseUsername == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Creating a user.");
            ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
            _user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            _user.setPassword("abc123");
            _user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, String.format("User '%s' created.", _user.getUsername()));
                        _progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        _appPrefs.saveParseUsername(_user.getUsername());
                        createStory();
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error creating user: ", e);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, String.format("Logging the user '%s' in with password '%s'.", parseUsername, "abc123"));
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(parseUsername, "abc123", new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "User logged in.");
                    _progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (e == null) {
                        createStory();
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error logging in: ", e);
                }
            });
        }
```

I can see the user being successfully created in the logs.  I can kill the app and re-launch but it always fails with "invalid login credentials" response from Parse.

If I manually enter `abc123` in the Parse data browser then everything works.  Ideas?

Comment: Is the user getting created in the Parse Data Browser? Also, you should check if the shared preferences actually get updated when you call '_appPrefs.saveParseUsername(_user.getUsername());' Ensure that there are no bugs in the saveParseUsername method.

Comment: Also, does this line ever get called 'Log.v(TAG, String.format("Logging the user '%s' in with password '%s'.", parseUsername, "abc123"));' ?

Comment: Note: At the bottom of the question I call out that the user is being created successfully and that I can manually set the password in the data browser -- which rectifies the problem ;)